# Can anybody explain the output of "mysql -V"?

Tags: mysql

For example,

```
# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.37-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

I think "Ver 15.1" means the version of the mysql client. But why does the client print  "Distrib 10.3.37-MariaDB" which I think is the version of mysql server? Considering a client can connect to different versions of server, why does it show a particular version?

Comment: The important part is `10.3.37-MariaDB` -- meaning that it is MariaDB (a spinoff of MySQL), version 10.3.37.  (That is rather old; you should consider upgrading soon--EOL expected 5/2023.)

Answer (score 1):

Everything after `mysql` in the `mysql -V` output is the mysql command-line client version information. It shows both the [version](https://mariadb.com/docs/skysql/ref/mdb/system-variables/version/) and the [version comment](https://mariadb.com/docs/skysql/ref/mdb/system-variables/version_comment/) set when building the binary.

> Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.37-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

That is for the client.

The source code of the MariaDB  `mysql` command line client  is included in the same source tree as the MariaDB server.  When the CLI binary gets built, it gets built with libraries and codes that have a specific Major, Minor and Patch [Version](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.3/VERSION) aligned with the MariaDB (server) release used. So in that regard it is expected that you see the same version numbers in the client as in the server. (When your installing both at the same time, from the same source (be it pre-compiled packages for your distribution or from source)

You are correct that generally the `mysql` CLI client is backwards and forward compatible with both older and newer version of both the MySQL and MariaDB database server.